# Combining multiple rasters into one

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

So, I have multiple rasters like this:

[image]

I have reclassified each raster into the same scale where values = 0,1,2,3. I'm trying to find areas where value = 3. I tried using the raster calculator with the following expression: `"R1"*"R2"*"R3"*"R4"`. But, I get the following result, why am I getting values greater than 3?

[image]

Comment: 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 = 81

Comment: @Hornbydd if you dont mind can you tell me what value=81 means?

Comment: In your question your state you are multiplying the 4 rasters `"R1"*"R2"*"R3"*"R4"`. so a pixel that is 3 in all rasters comes out as 81. What that means is up to your interpretation of your data.

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm trying to find areas where all 4 rasters combined have a value = 3, does multiplying do that?

Comment: If your 4 input rasters only ever have values 0 to 3 then if multiplied the only scenario that creates a value of 81 is when all 4 rasters have a 3 at the pixel, so that would be your scenario you are searching for.